# "gem install" freezes at "updating Gem source index for [..]"

Tags: windows, ruby, rubygems

For some weeks now I simply can't run gem install in windows.
It sticks on this line:

```
C:\Windows\System32>gem install rails --version 2.1.2
Bulk updating Gem source index for: http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you been able to install stuff previously?

The gem index is pretty big, about 26MB it seems - what sort of connection do you have? If you have dialup (or 512kbit "broadband" etc), it *will* take quite a while to update.

You could just grab the rails gem file and install it with `gem install rails.gem` - http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=307

Alternatively you could use one of the prepackage-rails installers, for example [InstantRails](http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/wiki/wiki.pl)

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem with gem version < 1.2. Upgrading to 1.2 fixed it.

Comment: sometime you need to manually upgrade by getting the correct version of the gem system because gem update -system doesn't work but will freeze as well.

Answer (score 1):

It worked fine on my Windows Server 2003 machine. I am using gem version 1.3.0.